# how to remove certain digits of a numeric variable in r

Tags: r, variables, transform, numeric

I have created `df1`

```
  year gvkey      ipo
1 1996  1004 19880101
2 1997  1004 19880101
3 1998  1004 19880101
4 1999  1004 19880101
5 2000  1004 19880101
6 2001  1004 19880101
....


year = numeric

gvkey (id) = numeric

ipo = numeric
```

I want to change `df1` so that it looks like this, so that I can calculate the firm age:

```
  year gvkey ipo
1 1996  1004 1988
2 1997  1004 1988
3 1998  1004 1988
4 1999  1004 1988
5 2000  1004 1988
6 2001  1004 1988
...
```

I have found a post where someone removed certain parts from a `character` variable. I tried to change `ipo` to `character` but then my `df1` turns into a value and when I try to change the value to a data frame again, the other variables, `year` and `gvkey`, are gone.

Is it also possible to just remove certain digits of a numeric variable?

Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1 %>%
  mutate(ipo = as.numeric(substr(ipo, 1, 4)))

  year gvkey  ipo
1 1996  1004 1988
2 1997  1004 1988
3 1998  1004 1988
4 1999  1004 1988
5 2000  1004 1988
6 2001  1004 1988
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `sub`

```
df1$ipo <- as.numeric(sub('^(....).*', '\\1', df1$ipo))
```